# Appcelerator iOS app is not full width

Tags: ios, titanium, width, appcelerator

I've developed update to my existing iOS app built with Appcelerator.
During development process it was tested on all iPhone simulators (5 - 6s) and real devices. Everything was working and displaying very good.

After deployment to AppStore, today after review I've updated app from AppStore and now it doesn't fill full width of screen [(please, see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq2XG.jpg).

What can be the reason and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: how do you style your views? Do you give it a fixed width?

Comment: Also try to know which iPhone was used to take that screenshot so that you can easily find out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this happens when you have a splashscreen in the wrong size. Can you check if you have all iPad splashscreens in the correct size